# Get JSON Object from php page which has php array using angular js http call

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, json, object

Below is my quetion

I am developing a angular project for learning purpose using php. I have a page where I am displaying a title, and text. I am sending http request to php class which is returning a array object(after fetching data from DB). Actually I need JSON object instead of php array. My array looks like below.

```
    <pre>
    array(2) {
        [0] => array(2) {
            ["title"] => string(32)
            "The twin towns of Moreh and Tamu" ["text"] => string(1047)
            "Despite the international border between them, the bazaar towns of Moreh in  past and one foot in."
        }[1] => array(2) {
            ["title"] => string(32)
            "The twin towns of Moreh and Tamu" ["text"] => string(1047)
            "Despite the international border between them, the bazaar towns of Moreh in  past and one foot in."
        }
    }
    </pre>
<p>Aboe is the php array $result. I have to get it like a JSON object. I tried json_encode($result) it is not working. I tried creating a string LIKE: 
<pre>$outp .= '{"title":"' .$result[0]['title'] .'","desc":[';  
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $outp .= '{"text":"' .$value['text'] .'"},';  
    } 
    $outp = substr($outp, 0, -1);
    $outp .= ']}]';
</p>
</pre>
<p>After printing the $result on php class itself, It looks like below:
<pre><b>And This is what i want</b>
[{
    "title": "The twin towns of Moreh and Tamu",
    "desc": [{
        "text": "Despite the international border between them, the bazaar towns of Moreh in  past and one foot in."
    }, {
        "text": "Despite the international border between them, the bazaar towns of Moreh in  past and one foot in."
    }]
}]
</pre>
<p>and I am returning the same to angular js. But angular js not able to read it.</p>
<h3>I want a JSON object from php class which has $result as php array</h3>
```

Comment: echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @Deep - already tried. it do not print andything. Instead it is returning boolean value.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: can you show me php code?

Comment: if your php array contains some special unicode characters then json_encode won't work